# json array with string and objects inside set mapping in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, mapping, elasticsearch-5, elk

here are two jsons:

json 1:

```
{
  "organization": [
    "Univ Philippines",
    {
      "pref": "Y",
      "content": "University of the Philippines System"
    },
    {
      "pref": "Y",
      "content": "University of the Philippines Diliman"
    }
  ]
}
```

json 2:

```
{
   "organization": "Univ Philippines"
}
```

I need index them into Elasticsearch. how to set `organization` field mapping?

I had tried `string` and `object` type but all failed.

```
PUT sci_test
{
  "mappings": {
    "sci":{
      "properties": {
        "organization":{
          "type": "object"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
PUT sci_test/sci/1
{
  "organization": [
    "Univ Philippines",
    {
      "pref": "Y",
      "content": "University of the Philippines System"
    },
    {
      "pref": "Y",
      "content": "University of the Philippines Diliman"
    }
  ]
}

error info:
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
        "reason": "object mapping for [organization] tried to parse field [null] as object, but found a concrete value"
      }
    ],
    "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
    "reason": "object mapping for [organization] tried to parse field [null] as object, but found a concrete value"
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the fields must of of same type. You cannot mix string with object

```
"Univ Philippines",                                      --> text
 {                                                       --> object
      "pref": "Y",
      "content": "University of the Philippines System"
 }"
```

You need to define "Univ Philippines" as "University":"Univ Philippines"(add some key "university" etc).